# (Mac OS 10.9) Boost.Python build quickstart: Unable to load Jamfile

Tags: macos, boost, macports, boost-python, boost-build

I have installed Boost 1.55 (+python33), `boost-build` and `boost-jam` through Macports on Mac OS X 10.9.
Following the HOWTO (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/python/doc/building.html), I
cd to /opt/local/share/doc/boost/libs/python/example/quickstart and typed in `bjam toolset=gcc
--verbose-test test` and just `bjam` and I got the following error message:

```
/opt/local/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:271: in find-jamfile from module project
error: Unable to load Jamfile.
error: Could not find a Jamfile in directory '../../../..'.
error: Attempted to find it with pattern '[Bb]uild.jam [Jj]amfile.v2 [Jj]amfile [Jj]amfile.jam'.
error: Please consult the documentation at 'http://www.boost.org'.
/opt/local/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:290: in load-jamfile from module project
/opt/local/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:68: in project.load from module project
/opt/local/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:718: in project.use from module project
/opt/local/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:95: in load-used-projects from module project
/opt/local/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:79: in load from module project
/opt/local/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:170: in project.find from module project
/opt/local/share/boost-build/build-system.jam:248: in load from module build-system
/opt/local/share/boost-build/kernel/modules.jam:261: in import from module modules
/opt/local/share/boost-build/kernel/bootstrap.jam:132: in boost-build from module
/opt/local/share/doc/boost/libs/python/example/quickstart/boost-build.jam:8: in module scope from module
```

Clearly the Macports put the files in some "non-default" locations. For example, the `boost-build` directory (specified in `boost-build.jam`) is in `/opt/local/share/doc/boost/tools/build/v2`. In the file `Jamroot`:

```
# Specify the path to the Boost project.  If you move this project,
# adjust the path to refer to the Boost root directory.
use-project boost 
  : ../../../.. ;
```

Clearly the desired jamefile is not in `../../../..` on Macports installation.

My question is: where is the desired jamefile located in Macports installation of boost? What path should I specify in `Jamroot`?

Comment: Not addressing your question, have you considered homebrew (http://brew.sh/)?

Comment: @AnthonyKong, no unless homebrew is absolutely necessary. I prefer macports taking care of things for me.